# Marshalling C++ char[] members results in empty string

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Im attempting to marshal a C++ struct containing char[] arrays to C# but on the unmanaged side I see the char arrays as empty and not sure what I'm missing

C# structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
public struct MParams
{
   public int action;
   public int response;
   public long serial_no;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 251)]
    public string address;  // public char[] address;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 81)]
   public string description; // public char[] description;
}
```

C++ Structure

```
typedef struct
{
  int                           action;
  int                           response;
  LONG                          serial_no;
  char                          address[251];
  char                          description[81];
}PARAMS;
```

C++ Exported function

```
__declspec(dllexport) (int) test_Email(void *params)
{
   PARAMS *l_params = (PARAMS *)params;
   // params->address // always empty expected abc@abc.com
}
```

C# Usage

```
[DllImport(@"test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint ="?test_Email@@YAHPAX@Z")]
public  static extern int EMailExists(IntPtr valParams);

MParams mParams = new MParams {
            action = 3,
            serial_no = 0,
            address = abc@abc.com,
            description = string.Empty
        };

IntPtr pAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(mParams));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(mParams, pAddr, false);
EMailExists(pAddr);
mParams = (MParams)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddr, typeof(MParams));
```

I've attempted using char[] to marshall but that too did not help. I reckon I'm missing on something very obvious and help to understand where I'm wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: You left out how you are filling those arrays on the C++ side.

Comment: In c++ a string is a char[] (one byte) terminated with a '\0'.  c#  a char is a class object where each character can be one or two bytes with a private property indicating if a character is one or two bytes.  Encoding methods have access to the private property when converting to/from a byte[] array.

Comment: The C# struct declaration is wrong, C++ LONG == C# int.

Comment: @HansPassant The declaration was indeed wrong and your suggestion resolved it.